# sed + regular expression: how to get everything before a given character

Tags: regex, sed

I have a property files that contains things like:

```
myhome=/home/username
lib=/home/libs
```

and I want to, for instance, get the home path (i.e. /home/username):

If I use cat + grep like

```
cat property | grep myhome
```

then I get: `myhome=/home/username`

so I could use sed to remove the 'home=', i.e. remove everything before (and including) the '='. How can I do that with sed ?

Cheers
David

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed -ne "s/^myhome=//p"
```

Answering to your comment below:

```
sed -ne "s/^[^=]\+=//p"
```

Comment: thanks! But is there a way of having a more generic expression where 'myhome' is not used, i.e. remove everything that before the '=' regardless of what is before '='

Comment: actually, I just tried "s/^[^=]+=//p" and it doesn't work... it returns nothing (with -ne) or everything with (-e)

Comment: Just tried this: ``echo "myhome=foo" | sed -ne 's/^[^=]*=//p'`` and taht results in "foo" being written on stdout. So, rplace the + with a * and all SHOULD be well.

Comment: fixed, plus should be escaped in sed regexp. plus suggests that line `=foo` should be left as is. `*` works too.

Answer (score 2):

use awk

```
awk -F"=" '{print $2}' file
awk '{sub(/^.[^=]*=/,"")}1' file
```

or just use the shell

```
while IFS="="  read -r a b
do
    echo $b
done <"file"
```

for sed, try this

```
sed -ne "s/^.[^=]*=//p" file
```

just shell string manipulation

```
$ myhome=/home/username=blah
$ echo ${myhome%%=}
/home/username=blah
```

Comment: thanks, I know awk better and thought of doing it just like you suggested, but I was trying to force myself to use/learn sed :-)

Comment: if you know awk, there is no need to know sed. the fundamentals of sed is regex. When you learn awk, you also learn regex.

Comment: I would argue that there is always a need to learn other tools... one day, you might have to deal with a project which uses sed only...and then you're stuffed

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's+.*=++g'
```

should do the job.

Comment: myhome=/home/username=john will be truncated to john

Comment: also empty lines and lines without `=` will be printed

Answer (score 1):

sed can do the greping for you, too.

```
$ sed -n -e "s/^myhome=//p" property
```

The `-n` is:

> suppress automatic printing of pattern space

While the trailing `p` prints a matched line.